# Is there an in-build function to add the created at date to a document in couchDB?

Tags: javascript, date, couchdb

When I create a new document in couchDB, I want that document to have an attribute `createdAt` where the exact date is stored when the document was created. I can create a timestamp using JavaScript but I was wondering whether there was a function in couchDB itself that does that kind of thing for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing is to use an [update handler](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers) each time you create a document. However, this will force you to use that update handler each time you create a document, and this will not catch documents that are created that bypass the update handler. (which isn't a problem unless you are exposing the database itself directly to the user)

Comment: Thanks Dominic, since I am creating my documents through javascript I will generate a timestamp using `(new Date()).getTime()`